# How to get top 10 row out of 100 and rank if each row having a rating in the range of 1 (Best) to 10 (Worst) in mysql

Tags: mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG6lH.jpg)

I want to sort top 10 codes on the basis of rating so that i can get result like below:

```
code|rating|rank
54383|4    | 1
24326|4    | 2
19580|6    | 3
```

Comment: So here is the question:- 
Assume there are 2500 PIN codes, every PIN code having a rating in the range of 1 (Best) to 10 (Worst). SELECT top 10 PIN codes along with their ratings

Comment: First of all try yourself after that show what did you done?

Comment: DONE already thank you for your advice @azam

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use `ORDER BY` or `limit`

```
SELECT code, rating, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank 
From table, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
ORDER BY rating DESC 
limit 10
```

Comment: yes i will, i have to wait 5 mins before i accept your answer